# Generate random number pairs of numbers in a range

Tags: ruby, random, numbers

I have a non-negative integer `articles.length`. I need to generate a list of `n` numbers of non-repeated pairs of numbers within the range `0...articles.length`, i.e. (for `articles.length == 10` and `n == 5`),

```
[[1, 3], [2, 6], [1, 6], [8, 1], [10, 3]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: If `articles` is there only to provide `articles.length`, then just give some variable that corresponds to  `articles.length` and not `articles`.

Comment: Can you clarify whether, say, `1, 2` and `2, 1` are the same pairing or different pairings?

Comment: I just noticed that your example is wrong. If the pair takes numbers from `0...10`, then you shouldn't have the pair `[10, 3]`.

Answer (score 4):

**Calculation**

```
mx = 10
n = 20
(0..(mx+1)**2-1).to_a.sample(n).map { |n| n.divmod(mx+1) }
  #=> [[6, 9], [3, 8], [7, 10], [3, 3], [2, 0], [8, 9], [4, 1], [9, 4], 
  #    [1, 0], [1, 8], [9, 6], [0, 10], [9, 0], [6, 8], [4, 9], [2, 10],
  #    [10, 0], [10, 5], [6, 10], [2, 9]]
```

**Explanation**

Sampling pairs of numbers, without replacement, is the same as sampling single numbers, without replacement, when there is a 1-1 map between two. Think of the single numbers as as 2-digit numbers in base `mx+1`, so each digit can range between `0` and `mx`, that is, corresponding to one element of a pair of numbers being sampled. There are `(mx+1)**2` two-digit base `mx+1` numbers, which, in base `10`, range from `0` to `(mx+1)**2-1`. We therefore need only sample `n` times from `(0..(mx+1)**2-1).to_a` and then use [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-divmod) to convert each sampled decimal number back to the two digits of the base `mx+1` number (in base `10`).

The procedure is clearly unbiased.

**Alternative method: generate pairs and discard duplicates**

If `(mx+1)**2-1)` is sufficiently large relative to `n`, the fastest way might well be the following (which also produces unbiased samples):

```
require 'set'

samp = Set.new
limit = mx+1
while samp.size < n
  samp << [rand(limit), rand(limit)]
end
samp.to_a
  #=> [[3, 6], [6, 2], [0, 3], [10, 0], [1, 8], [3, 4], [10, 3], [0, 4],
  #    [6, 7], [10, 7], [9, 1], [10, 5], [2, 7], [4, 8], [8, 4], [7, 3],
  #    [2, 4], [7, 10], [5, 3], [6, 3]]
```

I found that in the course of drawing random samples of `20` pairs `100` times (all for `mx = 10`), an average of `21.86` pairs were generated to be left with 20 unique pairs after the duplicates were discarded.

**Benchmarks**

I thought it might be interesting to benchmark several of the methods suggested.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'set'
```

It is convenient to put the methods to be tested in a module<sup>1</sup>.

```
module Candidates 
  def samp_with_difmod(mx, n)
    (0..(mx+1)**2-1).to_a.sample(n).map { |n| n.divmod(mx+1) }
  end

  def discard_dups(mx, n)
    samp = Set.new
    limit = mx+1
    while samp.size < n
      samp << [rand(limit), rand(limit)]
    end
    samp.to_a
  end

  def sawa_repeated_perm(mx, n)
    (0..mx).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).to_a.sample(n)
  end

  def sawa_product(mx, n)
    (0..mx).to_a.product((0..mx).to_a).sample(n)
  end
end
```

```
include Candidates
@candidates = Candidates.public_instance_methods(false)
  #=> [:samp_with_difmod, :discard_dups, :sawa_repeated_perm, :sawa_product]
@indent = candidates.map { |m| m.to_s.size }.max
  #=> 18

def bench(mx, n, reps)
  puts "\n0-#{mx}, sample size = #{n}, #{reps} reps"
  Benchmark.bm(@indent) do |bm|
    @candidates.each do |m|
      bm.report m.to_s do
        reps.times { send(m, mx, n) }
     end
    end
  end
end
```

```
bench(10, 20, 100)
0-10, sample size = 20, 100 reps
                         user     system      total        real
samp_with_difmod     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002536)
discard_dups         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005312)
sawa_repeated_perm   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004901)
sawa_product         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004742)
```

```
bench(100, 20, 100)
0-100, sample size = 20, 100 reps
                         user     system      total        real
samp_with_difmod     0.031250   0.015625   0.046875 (  0.088003)
discard_dups         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.005618)
sawa_repeated_perm   0.093750   0.000000   0.093750 (  0.136010)
sawa_product         0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.138848)
```

```
bench(10, 121, 100)
0-10, sample size = 121, 100 reps
                         user     system      total        real
samp_with_difmod     0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003283)
discard_dups         0.171875   0.015625   0.187500 (  0.208459)
sawa_repeated_perm   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004253)
sawa_product         0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002947)
```

In the above the sampling is done from a population of `11**2 #=> 121`. Drawing a sample of `121`, without replacement, from a population of `121` means that the sample is comprised of all pairs in the population. It is not surprising, therefore, that `discard_dups` does relatively poorly. After having drawn 120 unique pairs, for example, it will continually reject duplicates until it stumbles onto the remaining pair that has not made its way into the sample.

```
bench(100, 100, 100)
0-100, sample size = 100, 100 reps
                         user     system      total        real
samp_with_difmod     0.046875   0.000000   0.046875 (  0.042177)
discard_dups         0.031250   0.000000   0.031250 (  0.029467)
sawa_repeated_perm   0.109375   0.000000   0.109375 (  0.132429)
sawa_product         0.125000   0.000000   0.125000 (  0.140451)
```

```
bench(1000, 500, 10)
0-1000, sample size = 500, 10 reps
                         user     system      total        real
samp_with_difmod     0.437500   0.140625   0.578125 (  0.632434)
discard_dups         0.015625   0.000000   0.015625 (  0.013634)
sawa_repeated_perm   1.718750   0.359375   2.078125 (  2.166724)
sawa_product         1.734375   0.062500   1.796875 (  1.853555)
```

In this last benchmark, where the maximum value (`1000`) is both large and large relative to the sample size (`500`), `discard_dups` is the clear winner. Here the size of the sample space is `1001**2 #=> 1_002_001`, so `discard_dups` would encounter relatively few duplicates in drawing a sample of size `500`.

`sawa_product` does quite a bit better than `sawa_repeated_perm` but in the other tests the performance of the two methods is similar.

<sup>1 Including a module containing the methods to be tested simplifies the code and makes it easy to add, remove and rename methods to be tested.</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately you still have to generate the whole array of numbers in order to sample, so this isn't more efficient than [sawa's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53644647/477037).

Comment: @Stefan, it is true that we are generating the same number of elements from which to sample (which is unavoidable for randomness), but the comparison is between `(0..(mx+1)**2-1).to_a` and `(0...10).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).to_a`, the first clearly being faster. The former is also more storage-efficient as the elements of the array are integers whereas sawa is generating tuples. It is true, however, that I have the extra step using `divmod` but I wouldn't expect that to be significant. It's times like these when I wish there were a method `Range#sample`.

Comment: Thinking of how `Range#sample` could be implemented I see no good way that does not involve converting the range to an array, which probably explains why we don't have that method.

Comment: Thank you for the inspiration. I built an Enumerator based on your logic to allow for a continual generation of n elements without the need to generate the full set (@Stefan :)) however you can retrieve the full set if you'd like.

Comment: @engineersmnky, can you post that as an answer? I don't understand how you could do that, for if you use `sample` it's only defined for arrays.

Comment: [Benchmarks and Rankings](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/permutationenumerator) the enum is slower than `discard_dups` probably due to set up penalties and the flexibility of `Array#new` implementation. However it is very difficult to tell since the hit counts between the 2 will be consistently inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Not the most efficient, but the following works.

```
(0...10).to_a.repeated_permutation(2).to_a.sample(5)
#=> [[8, 4], [2, 9], [5, 0], [5, 4], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: BTW, `ary.repeated_permutation(2).to_a` is just `ary.product(ary)`

Comment: Yes, that may be shorter, but then you have to write `ary` in two places, which is a minor drawback.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this regularly we can create an Enumerator that does this for us: (Thank you [@CarySwoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645670/1978251) for the conceptual math and use of `Set`)

```
require 'set'
def generator(limit,size=2) 
  enum_size = (limit.is_a?(Range) ? limit.size : limit += 1) ** size 
  if enum_size.infinite?
    limit = limit.is_a?(Range) ? (limit.first..Float::MAX.to_i) : Float::MAX.to_i
  end       
  Enumerator.new(enum_size) do |y| 
    s = Set.new
    loop do 
      new_rand = Array.new(size) { rand(limit) }
      y << new_rand if s.add?(new_rand)
      raise StopIteration if s.size == enum_size
    end
  end
end
```

Now getting `n` pairs does not require us to generate all the possible permutations before sampling. Instead we generate `n` random pairs on demand. (not to exceed the maximum number of permutations possible).

Usage:

```
g = combination_generator(10)
g.take(5)
#=> [[10, 4], [9, 6], [9, 9], [2, 6], [4, 6]]
g.take(5)
#=> [[9, 7], [2, 8], [2, 2], [8, 8], [7, 3]]
g.to_a.sort
#=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10], 
#    [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [1, 8], [1, 9], [1, 10], 
# ..., [10,10]]
```

Works with Ranges too like `generator((2..7))` will only generate combinations between `[2,2]` and `[7,7]`.

Additionally I added the ability to allow for any number of sub set elements without sacrificing the speed of generation e.g.

```
g = generator((0..Float::INFINITY),20)
g.size 
#=>  Infinity 
g.first
#=> [20 extremely large numbers]
require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
  x.report(:fast) { g.first(10) } 
  x.report(:large_fast) { g.first(10_000) } 
end

# Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
# fast         0.000552   0.000076   0.000628 (  0.000623)
# large_fast   0.612065   0.035515   0.647580 (  0.672739)
# ------------------------------------- total: 0.648208sec
#                  user     system      total        real
# fast         0.000728   0.000000   0.000728 (  0.000744)
# large_fast   0.598493   0.000000   0.598493 (  0.607784)
```

Comment: I just noticed your answer and will add it to my benchmark tomorrow morning.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't expect it to fair as well as the others (full set generation shows about 11 to 20% efficiency) . My design was to handle things the other options couldn't like infinite sets and 20 element permutations.

Comment: Ah, I see. Interesting idea.

Comment: @CarySwoveland thank you; however it is about half as efficient as your `discard_dup` excepting, `mx =10; n = 122`, in which case it is infinitely more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

Only if `n <= s` and if a pair containing equals elements is acceptable:

```
def random_pairs n, s
  res = []
  (1..n).to_a.tap { |a| res = a.sample(s).zip(a.sample(s)) }
  res
end

random_pairs 10, 5
#=> [[6, 5], [1, 1], [9, 6], [8, 4], [4, 7]]
```

Pairs are not repeated, but there can be a pair containing equals elements: `[1,1]`

---

To follow the comments, but much slower:

```
def random_pairs_bis n, s
  res = []
  s.times {(1..n).to_a.tap { |a| res << a.shuffle.zip(a.shuffle) }}
  res.flatten(1).uniq.sample(s)
end
```

Comment: This approach limits the possible results, e.g. you'll never get `[1, 2]` and `[1, 6]` in the same output (as shown in the OP's example).

Comment: @Stefan, actually i miss it. But you can `(random_pairs(10, 10) + random_pairs(10, 10)).sample(5)` to get it.

Comment: That could result in duplicates.

Comment: @Stefan, grrr! :) `(random_pairs(10, 10) + random_pairs(10, 10)).uniq.sample(5)`

Comment: That would allow at most two `[1, x]` but no more.

Answer (score 0):

This might be sufficient to answer OP:

```
articles = ["apples","pencils","chairs","pencils","guitars","parsley", "ink","stuff" ]
n = 5
p random_pairs = Array.new(n){articles.sample(2) }

# => [["parsley", "apples"], ["pencils", "chairs"], ["pencils", "apples"], ["stuff", "apples"], ["stuff", "guitars"]]
```

Comment: No. This can lead to duplicate pairs. It is not correct.